# Accessing inline fields within inline get_formset in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have the following example where I have buildings(address, location,...) and apartments(name, size, type, building). One building containing multiple apartments.

```
class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ApartmentInline,]

class ApartmentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super(ApartmentInline, self).get_formset(request, obj=None, **kwargs)

        #Here i'd like to see the values of inline fields, for example size or building that.
        #Similar to how one can access ModelAdmin fields with obj.location within get_form

        formset.form.base_fields["type"].widget = SelectMultiple(choices=custom_choices)
        return formset
```

I'd like to be able to get the current apartments instance and field values when editing the object (for example size), so that I can create custom choices (querying other DB's or API's) for another field (type).

Answer (score 0):

To modify the inline form widget you can override `ModelInlineForm` which gives each inline `instance` access after initializing.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import resolve


class ApartmentInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = (
            '...',
            '...',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # calculate widget choices
        self.fields['type'].widget = SelectMultiple(choices=custom_choices)

class ApartmentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Apartment
    form = ApartmentInlineForm
```

Comment: The parent object is already acessible, what I want to find is a way to access the individual instance of each of the inlines..

Comment: @drec4s sorry for that, I updated the answer to use the InlineForm instead